firebase module compiled with incompatible version of Kotlin version 1.9.9999?

firebase-auth-api_firebase-auth-api.kotlin_module: Module was compiled
with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its
metadata is 1.9.9999, expected version is 1.7.1.

I'm  at wits end. I've tried virtually everything. This error has sporadically popped up over the last 2 years, but now I can't get past it. Debug version compiles fine. The release version doesn't. All dependencies up to date.
I've followed countless advise of others who have had similar issues. I've cleared caches, deleted folders, and back-dated kotlin versions and dependencies. 1.9.9999, is that even a real version number?
build.gradle (project):
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    ext {
        kotlin_version = "2.0.21"
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2'
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.9.10' apply false
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics' version '2.9.9' apply false
}

build.gradle (app):
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
}
android {
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('***')
            storePassword '***'
            keyAlias '***'
            keyPassword '***'
        }
        release {
            storeFile file('***')
            storePassword '***'
            keyAlias '***'
            keyPassword '***'
        }
    }
    namespace "***"
    compileSdk 34
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "***"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "one"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            crunchPngs true
            debuggable false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            debuggable true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
        viewBinding true
        buildConfig true
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity:1.9.3'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.8.5'
    implementation(platform('org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.9.0'))

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.5.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'

    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.7.3'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.7.3'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.7.3'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.15.1'
    implementation "com.tbuonomo:dotsindicator:5.0"
}


Can you share your build.gradle?
